# Replace placeholders with Map values using indexOf

Tags: java, string, hashmap, substring, indexof

I am trying to use indexOf to find placeholders in a String ("${...}").
My small example below works fine so far, but obviously only for the first occurence. How could I change this code to be able to go through all the placeholders and rebuild the String in the end. The input String can be random and doesn't have a set number of placeholders in it. Not really sure where to go from here.

```
// example Hashmap
HashMap <String, String> placeHolderMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
placeHolderMap.put("name", "device");
placeHolderMap.put("status", "broken");
placeHolderMap.put("title", "smartphone");

// input String
String content = "This ${name} is ${status} and categorized as ${title} in the system";
int left = content.indexOf("${");
int right = content.indexOf("}");

// getting the name of the placeholder, if the placeholdermap contains the placeholder as a key it sets the placeholder to the corresponding value
String contentPlaceHolder = content.substring(left+2, right);
if (placeHolderMap.containsKey(contentPlaceHolder)){
    contentPlaceHolder = placeHolderMap.get(contentPlaceHolder);
}
content = content.substring(0, left) + contentPlaceHolder + content.substring(right+1);
```

Currently, the output would be "This device is ${status} and categorized as ${title} in the system"

Comment: how about [this library](https://github.com/holi-java/rstring/blob/master/src/test/java/com/holi/RStringVariableReplacementTest.java#L25-L29)? it is wrote for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a String.replaceAll() method?

```
    Map<String, String> placeHolderMap = new HashMap<>();
    placeHolderMap.put("\\$\\{name}", "device");
    placeHolderMap.put("\\$\\{status}", "broken");
    placeHolderMap.put("\\$\\{title}", "smartphone");


    // input String
    String content = "This ${name} is ${status} and categorized as ${title} in the system";

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : placeHolderMap.entrySet()) {
          content = content.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

**Update** Stefan, Neil and Kennet, thank you.

UPDATE 17/07/17
You can also use String.replace() method which does not use regex, or, alternatively, use Pattern.quote() method:

```
    Map<String, String> placeHolderMap = new HashMap<>();
    placeHolderMap.put("${name}", "device");
    placeHolderMap.put("${status}", "broken");
    placeHolderMap.put("${title}", "smartphone");


    // input String
    String content = "This ${name} is ${status} and categorized as ${title} in the system";

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : placeHolderMap.entrySet()) {
          content = content.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          // content = content.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: String is immutable, therefore calling "replaceAll" serves no purpose if you don't retain the returned value.

Comment: String.replaceAll uses regex and gives java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
${title} when you changed placeholder keys from OPs example

Comment: This seems to work just fine for what I was trying to achieve, thanks for helping everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your method recusively:

```
private String replace(String content) {
    int left = content.indexOf("${");
    if (left < 0) {
        // breaking the recursion
        return content;
    }
    int right = content.indexOf("}");

    // getting the name of the placeholder, if the placeholdermap contains the placeholder as a key it sets the placeholder to the corresponding value
    String contentPlaceHolder = content.substring(left + 2, right);
    if (placeHolderMap.containsKey(contentPlaceHolder)) {
        contentPlaceHolder = placeHolderMap.get(contentPlaceHolder);
    }
    content = content.substring(0, left) + contentPlaceHolder + content.substring(right + 1);
    return replace(content);
}
```

Comment: This may work, but surely "replaceAll" would be a more graceful solution than indexOf and recursive calls?

Comment: @Neil if it is homework and it is specified to not use `replaceAll`? It just used OP's specification

Comment: @Neil "replaceAll" can also have drawbacks. Since if a string has repeated placeholders, it will behave wrong.

Comment: @YuriHeiko Recursive calls means if you're replacing more than 100 strings, this method will crash.  Searching for `${` and `}` is not ideal either since if there is a `${` in the string without an equivalent `}`, this will crash.  Overall not a very robust solution.  `replaceAll` addresses both these problems.